State Space with a different state equation version and without autoregression
I am using State Space to model a specific computation in my NNs, however, I have two main questions.

Is it possible to not use the standard state transition equation? More specifically, my states concern the Loss, which is something computed by my network, through the use of the categorical cross-entropy loss, so I do not see the point in me updating it in a different way for now.
Due to what I mentioned above, I do not have the autoregression in what I have defined, so I am wondering if it goes out of the State Space notion, or if it could also be another version of it.

